# Explanation: This is not a cross-product set. Therefore, U and V are not independent.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let U=the number of trials needed to get the first head and V= the number of trials needed to get two heads in repeated tosses of a fair coin. Are U and V independent random variables?

I know the answer is NOT. But the solution said:

> The support of the distribution of (U, V ) is {$(u, v) : u = 1, 2, . . . ; v = u + 1, u + 2, . . .$}. This
> is not a cross-product set. Therefore, U and V are not independent. More simply, if we know
> U = u, then we know V > u.

I understand the logic. But I don't understand what "a cross-product set" mean. What's that?

Comment: I assume they mean that it isn't a set which can be written as the Cartesian product of two sets, which I'd say was a strange way of phrasing the argument. Here, of course, if the variables were independent, you'd expect the support to be the product of the two supports.  Their "more simply" argument is much clearer.  Even simpler:  Knowing that $V=2$ determines $U$ uniquely.

Comment: I think the point is that the marginal distribution of $V$ has support on $2,3,4,\ldots$ but, if say $U\not=1$, then the conditional support of $V$  is different (we know $V>U$), so they cannot be independent